# Konva.js How can I resize the image with fixed position?

Tags: konvajs, react-konva, konva

I'm trying to resize image with `Transformer`.
The problem lies that when the image is resized, the image is not fixed and moves as much as it is reduced in that direction.

For these reasons, I removed offset `offsetX={image ? image.width / 2 : 0} offsetY={image ? image.height / 2 : 0}` in `Image` tag then now the image is dropped based on the left side `Transformer`'s first point.

codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/embed/romantic-moon-d9cer?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

any and all help is greatly appreciated.